# Add a custom .d.ts file into my project

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, tsd, stamplay

I'm using [StamplayAPI Javascript](https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-js-sdk), but there is no set type for this library.
So I [created a type](https://github.com/Ridermansb/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/stamplay-js-sdk/stamplay-js-sdk.d.ts) `.d.ts` for this library and did a [pull request](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/5958). But I would not want to wait for the acceptance of the pull request to start using my type.

How can I start using my type with the tsd?

Is there any way to install a type of an outside source .. something like

```
tsd install stamplay-js-sdk --source /my/git/repo/or/path/to/folder
```

Comment: you can do this manually - just copy your file into your project and add reference to it something like
``///<reference path="somepath/stamplay-js-sdk.d.ts"/>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `"repo": "Ridermansb/DefinitelyTyped",` into your `tsd.json`.